# Why function colis(collision) doesn't work?

Tags: python

Function doesn't work

I tried to make a game, and at the some point all start going wrong.(my english isn't best, i know, sorry)

I use library pygame for my project. I made a function which detect the contact of objects, but when i start the game function doesn't work. I tried to start it without function and then all start working. I'm  wondering why the function doesn't work. I hope that you can tell me something about it.

In the file sets i wrote some variables like speed.

```
from sets import *

import pygame as pg

import time

pg.init()

sc = pg.display.set_mode((1280,720))

test = pg.Surface((100,100))

test.fill((122,122,122))

block = pg.Surface((50,50))

block.fill((0,0,0))

def colis(x,y,player_width,player_height,width,height,xx,yy):

    if x + player_width > xx:

        if x < xx + width - 20:

            if y + player_height > yy + 10:

                if y < yy + height - 10:

                    x = xx - player_width

    if x < xx + width:

        if x > xx:

            if y + player_height > yy + 10:

                if y < yy + height - 10:

                    x = xx + width

    if y < yy + height:

        if y > yy + 20:

            if x + player_width > xx:

                if x < xx + width:

                    y = yy + height

    if y + player_height > yy:

        if y < yy + height - 20:

            if x + player_width > xx:

                if x < xx + width:

                    y = yy - player_height

while True:

    clock.tick(60)

    for event in pg.event.get():

        if event.type == pg.QUIT:

            run = False

            pg.QUIT

        elif event.type == pg.KEYDOWN:

            if event.key == pg.K_w:

                w = 1

            if event.key == pg.K_a:

                a = 1

            if event.key == pg.K_s:

                s = 1

            if event.key == pg.K_d:

                d = 1

    if w > 0:

        w += speed

        if w > 10:

            w = 0

    if a > 0:

        a += speed

        if a > 10:

            a = 0

    if s > 0:

        s += speed

        if s > 10:

            s = 0

    if d > 0:

        d += speed

        if d > 10:

            d = 0

    x += d - a

    y += s - w

    colis(x,y,50,50,100,100,200,200)

    

    

    pg.display.update()

    sc.fill((255,255,255))

    sc.blit(block,(x,y))

    sc.blit(test,(xx,yy))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your function `colis` doesn't do anything. There is no return value. All it does is change the values of a few local variables, variables which go out of scope when the function finishes. Thus the function call `colis(x,y,50,50,100,100,200,200)` has no effect. The values of `x` and `y` are not changed by the function call.

Instead, return `x` and `y` from the function:

```
def colis(x,y,player_width,player_height,width,height,xx,yy):

    if x + player_width > xx:
        if x < xx + width - 20:
            if y + player_height > yy + 10:
                if y < yy + height - 10:
                    x = xx - player_width

    if x < xx + width:
        if x > xx:
            if y + player_height > yy + 10:
                if y < yy + height - 10:
                    x = xx + width

    if y < yy + height:
        if y > yy + 20:
            if x + player_width > xx:
                if x < xx + width:
                    y = yy + height

    if y + player_height > yy:
        if y < yy + height - 20:
            if x + player_width > xx:
                if x < xx + width:
                    y = yy - player_height
    return x,y
```

(I eliminated most of the blank lines since all those blank lines makes it harder to read).

After that change, replace `colis(x,y,50,50,100,100,200,200)` by

```
x,y = colis(x,y,50,50,100,100,200,200)
```

Disclaimer: I don't have pygame installed so am unable to see if there are any other problems with your code, but making the above changes will at least give you code which makes more sense.

Comment: Shouldn't the function return just a boolean, if it's purpose is to detect collisions?

Comment: @dodekja That would certainly make more sense, but I was going by OP's function call `colis(x,y,50,50,100,100,200,200)`. The only explanation for that line is that they thought that `x` and `y` would be changed by that call. Furthermore, the code in `colis` doesn't really seem to be computing a boolean but is instead assigning values to `x` and `y`. The point of my answer was to alert them to the importance of returning values and using those return values.